# Displaying multiple Text Files on screen in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code successfully reads in one text file and allows it to then be displayed as a GUI Label. I was wondering how I would do this for multiple text files? I wouldn't want them together just as individual Labels, I was thinking possibly Arrays or Lists but I wouldn't be sure.
Thank you for you help

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour
{
public StreamReader reader = null;
public FileInfo theSourceFile = null;

public void Start()
    {
          theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
          if (theSourceFile != null && theSourceFile.Exists)
            reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
        if (reader == null)
        {
          Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
        }
        else
        {
          while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
                completeText += txt + "\n";
             }
          }
        }

public void OnGUI()
    {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab))
            {
                GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), completeText);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class, add a list of strings:

```
private List<string> _allFiles = new List<string>();
```

Separate `Start()` to another method and call that for each of your files. At the end of each process, add the `completeText` variable to that list as shown below:

```
public void Start()
{
    theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/puzzles.txt");
    ProcessFile(theSourceFile);

    // set theSourceFile to another file
    // call ProcessFile(theSourceFile) again
}

private void ProcessFile(FileInfo file)
{

      if (file != null && file.Exists)
        reader = file.OpenText();
    if (reader == null)
    {
      Debug.Log("puzzles.txt not found or not readable");
    }
    else
    {
      while ((txt = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("-->" + txt);
            completeText += txt + "\n";
         }

         _allFiles.Add(completeText);
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `OnGui()` method, add a loop around the `GUI.Label` call.

```
int i = 1;
foreach(var file in _allFiles)
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50 + (i * 400), 400, 400), file);
    i++;
}
```

This assumes that you want the labels to appear vertically, and with no gap between them.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post my answer in answers so you can see code clearly! :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for you reply again! Okay so now the both texts are appearing but they now both appear on each label together - I guess this is what the shifting Variables thing is so each file can be selected in the foreach? Could you possibly show me how to do that if you have time? Thank you so much :D

Comment: The Labels actually appear when you hover over a model so I never want them on screen at the same time. Your solution works great but both text files now appear together and I don't know how to access them from the list separately as having file at the end of the GUI label just brings both together?

Comment: OK, I think it's gone beyond the original scope of the question now. You want to be able to identify which model goes with which file, and load the contents accordingly - you may need to have a deeper architectural change to do this neatly. My answer here is only good for displaying the contents of several files underneath each other at the same time, not for choosing one in particular. You probably want a `Dictionary` of some sort...